# Scanning for attributes in C# 2012

Tags: c#

Is there a new method introduced for scanning the attributes of the files selected in VS 2012 C#? For example scanning an attribute of a file such as read only, system and hidden for making an antivirus.

Comment: Erm, no.  What on Earth makes you think there is?

Comment: Please comment on how existing once are not working for your or in what way you want to see them changed.

Comment: actually somebody told me there is. I was making sure.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no new method, the old one worked just fine. Here is an untested Example of the method that currently exists

```
Directory.GetFiles("path").Select(file => File.GetAttributes(file) == FileAttributes.ReadOnly);
```